# Notepad++: How to delete everything before a specific word, then everything after another word, leaving the word in the middle

Tags: replace, notepad++

Trying to figure out how to remove all text up until the phrase "gene:", keeping the bold letters/numbers, then removing everything that comes after the bold.

> ENSP00000488240.1 pep chromosome:GRCh38:CHR_HSCHR7_2_CTG6:142847306:142847317:1 gene:**ENSG00000282253**.1 transcript:ENST00000631435.1 gene_biotype:TR_D_gene transcript_biotype:TR_D_gene gene_symbol:TRBD1 description:T cell receptor beta diversity 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12158]
> GTGG

I've tried the following command line in find: but it isn't working. It just highlights the entire file. If I uncheck ".matches newline", then it highlights the entire line.

Find: ^>.+gene:(ENSG\d+)..+

Replace: >\1

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to clarify whether 'highlights anything' means that it highlights the entire file, or the entire line.

If it highlights the entire applicable line(s) only, then a replacement should work as intended. If not, also verify that ". matches newline" is unchecked.

Comment: It highlights the entire file. If I uncheck ".matches newline", then it highlights the entire line.

Comment: After it highlights the entire line, try clicking the button to replace the content. It should highlight the entire area that you're *searching* for, but it'll still only use the area you *captured* between those parentheses in your replacement. If that does not work, you may want to wait for a proper answer.

Comment: Wow I can't believe it was that simple! Thanks for the help.